# How can i get a list of running app with nodejs

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to get all the running app information with nodejs or electron on every os with a generic code.

So far i was using all **desktopCapturer.getSources** from the electron api https://electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer that worked fine until now but on macos it only get the current desktop running app information.

If there is 3 different app running on 3 different desktop how can i get an information list of those app on every os (id, title, ...) with nodejs or electron ?

Comment: do yo mean, you want to know every app that is running in background ?

Comment: @raman I meant that i want to know every ui app running on every desktop not in background :)

Comment: @AdamSoto Did you find the solution?

Comment: Sadly not, i think someone has to code a native module with nodejs bindings in order to do it. The only app i saw having the full list so far is zoom, it means there is a way @AdilMalik